# "set/p" doesn't work, I can't make out how "set" works

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

```
@echo off
REM turning off the output of commands to the screen
Set /P "%~1=Extension: "
if "%~1" == "" echo Extension not introduced
REM if you do not enter anything, the extension is not entered
if not exist "*.%~1" echo No files found
REM if you entered an extension that does not exist, it will give you no files found.
DEL /Q "*.%~1"
REM delete files with the specified extension without confirmation
```

I can't figure out how "set" works. Help to make it so that: after launching batch, you had to enter the extension and then it would be deleted or output that it was not found.

Comment: You might find [SS64 on `SET`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to be useful, and note that it is NOT considered good practice - if it's even possible - to attempt to change the values of the numeric positional parameters.

Comment: Your code, if no input argument is received, is trying to define a variable with no name! (`Set /P "<nothing>=Extension: "`), and clearly you cannot define a variable without a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(not really worth an answer, but comments are not good at displaying readable code)

`%~1` is the first parameter to the script. When I understand you correctly, you don't want any parameters, but you want the script to ask for input.

You have to use a variable (`%variable%`) instead of a parameter then:

```
@echo off
:label
set /p "ext=" & REM clear variable because `set /p` leaves it unchanged when you enter nothing
Set /P "ext=please enter Extension: "
if "%ext%" == "" echo Extension not introduced & goto :label
if not exist "*.%ext%" echo No files found & goto :label
DEL /Q "*.%ext%"
```

(removed the comments and added some basic "code flow")

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try to simplify your flow by using `If`'s, labels, and `GoTo`'s?

Example

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Ext) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "Ext=%~1"
If Defined Ext GoTo ChkExt

:GetExt
ClS
Set /P "Ext=Enter extension [without leading period]>"
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo GetExt

:ChkExt
Set Ext | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "." 1>NUL
If Not ErrorLevel 1 GoTo GetExt

:DelExt
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Delete all %Ext% files in %CD%"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :EOF
Del /A /F /Q "*.%Ext%"
```

If the end user runs the batch file using a valid format extension as an input argument, it should offer to delete all files with that extension, otherwise it will prompt them for the extension.